# Does attending a Siyum receive the merit as if one has learned the whole Masechta (Tractate)?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, reward-punishment, siyum

I've heard people say that attending a Siyum gets the merit like you learned all of the Gemara that's getting Siyum'd on.

Is there a mekor (Torah source) for this idea?

(And if yes, then does any Sefer explain that it's not exactly the same reward? It's hard for me to understand that the partaker gets the same full reward as the person that spent 100's of hours working on the Gemara.)

Thank you for any help regarding this

Comment: The Sdei Chemed explains that if you learn a mashechta as part of a chabura finishing shas,then when they are misyaim it is counted like you have completed the whole shas. See Mareches Mem 198

Comment: Someone told me similarly but not exactly the same in the name of the Gra

Comment: Perhaps this is played off Rashi’s explanation of ימא טבא לרבנן

Comment: What's the point of "getting the merit" if you haven't learned the material?

Comment: Wow, thanks Sam. So at least we have a mekor for someone that learned as part of the collective group's accomplishment.  And in response to Maurice: Granted I don't understand how the "schar" (merit) actually works, but after 120 years, a person will see that he gains an incredible amount for each merit he earned. There will be tremendous significance for any merit one accrues in this prozdor (hallway) world.